read issues during Concurrent fwrite to NFS
I have two processes: one is writing to a file in a loop using fwrite, and another is reading the file in a loop using read. The reader process sometimes returns positive read size but all 0x00 in the buffer, but when it tries to read again, it works fine. The file is located on a networked file system, wekafs, and the reading process occurs while the writer is still writing to the file (live reading).
Here’s the code for the reader process:
#include <iostream>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    const char* filename = "<my file>";
    
    // Open the file for reading
    int fd = open(filename, O_DIRECT | O_RDONLY);
    if (fd < 0) {
        perror("Failed to open file for reading");
        return 1;
    }

    size_t sz = 40000;
    char *read_data;
    if (posix_memalign((void**)&read_data, 512, sz) != 0) {
        perror("Failed to allocate aligned memory");
        return 1;
    }

    bool loop = true;
    size_t total_bytes = 0;

    while (loop) {
        ssize_t bytes_read = read(fd, read_data, sz);
        if (bytes_read < 0) {
            perror("Failed to read from file");
            break;
        } else if (bytes_read == 0) {
            std::cout << "End of file reached." << std::endl;
            break;
        } else {
            total_bytes += bytes_read;
            std::cout << "Read " << bytes_read << " bytes, total so far: " << total_bytes << std::endl;
        }
    }

    // Clean up
    free(read_data);
    close(fd);

    return 0;
}

Issue:
Sometimes, when the reader attempts to read, it gets all zeros in the buffer, which I assume is garbage data. When the reader tries again, it works fine.
The writer is continuously writing to the file, and the reader reads from the file in real-time, while the file is being modified (live reading).
The file is located on a wekafs network file system, and I'm not sure if the problem is related to network latency or caching issues with the file system.
What I’ve tried:
Ensured the reader is checking for errors properly (i.e., checking for read() return values).
Could the issue be related to how the network file system handles live reads and writes, or is there something else I’m missing in handling the reader-writer synchronization?

You really need some kind of synchronization between the two processes, so the reader doesn't read until the writer has finished writing, Same for the other way around, the writer shouldn't write while the reader is reading. This is a very simple and classic problem.

@Someprogrammerdude In my scenario, the writer is appending data to the file, while the reader is processing it byte by byte. I expect the reader to only receive valid, written data and not any garbage or incomplete information.

If you replace std::cout with puts and printf, it becomes pure C code. I don't see any signs of C++ in this snippet. Nor does the question directly address any C++ related problem.

As you use fwrite, your writing process uses buffered IO. This means, that some data in application buffer and some data in NFS clients local page cache, and synced will the NFS server on memory pressure or on close. However, the reader process uses direct IO, thus reads data that is on the NFS server. To ensure that the written data is available to the client the writer process should either use direct IO, or call fflush to sync application buffer, followed by fsync on file descriptor to push the data to the NFS server.

If this were the reason, the reader process would not read 0x00 (garbage value). Instead, it might face a delay in retrieving the correct data due to synchronization issues. Am I right?

You can get zeros as a result of a sparse read. The file size was updated, but the data was not. This, however, is not what clients expect (and should happen). Keep in mind that NFS provides close-to-open cache consistency, which means that it is guaranteed to see the file content on read after the writer process has issues closed.
